# Issue with FullCallendar refreshing page when event is clicked

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I have installed Full Calendar on my site and find it seems to fire off a page refresh when an Calendar Event is clicked..  This doesn't happened when a date is selected or event added.   Only existing calendar events fires off the Refresh.. how do I make it stop?

Comment: Have you added the `url` property to your fullCalendar event data? That will cause the browser to navigate to that URL when an event is clicked. If not, then we'll need to see enough code and data to be able to investigate your problem. This isn't default behaviour, so there must be something related to how you have implemented it. Your question lacks enough detail for us to understand the issue, we need more information.

Comment: P.S. As you're new to StackOverflow (welcome!) 
I suggest you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) which you were recommended to do when you signed up for StackOverflow (but I can see from your profile that you haven't) and read the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide. That way you'll have a better idea of what a good question looks like, and then you can update yours to improve its quality, and therefore improve your chances of getting an answer. These resources are here to help you have a good experience on StackOverflow, so please use them. Thanks.